# How to 'get' an activity made wiith activity browser in Brightway

Tags: brightway

I am relatively new with Brightway and the Activity Browser, so please be patient. But I have trouble 'getting' an activity from Brightway that I have created in the Activity Browser. I have created a database in the Activity Browser called 'Potato' and a process called 'Potato - FI - production". WHen I search for the process in Brightway it finds it, but when I want to 'get' the activity to set a functional unit I get a error message 'ActivityDatasetDoesNotExist'. Can someone tell me why this does not work?

'''
PO = potato.search("Potato - FI - production")
print(PO)

['Potato - FI - production' (kilogram, FI, None)]
'''

'''
PO2 = bw.Database('Potato').get("Potato - FI - production")

ActivityDatasetDoesNotExist
'''

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` requires the activity *code*, not its *name*. Codes are normally autogenerated, so look like random nonsense.

You can do:

`PO2 = [act for act in bw.Database('Potato') if name == "Potato - FI - production"][0]`

In Brightway 2.5 (development version, not yet compatible with the Activity Browser), you can do:

`PO2 = bw.get_node(database="Potato", name="Potato - FI - production")`

Comment: Thank you Chris! I will try your suggestions :). I think I might have done something else wrong as well. I somehow overwrote the entire database when trying to add a few processes to the database in Brightway. I guess what happened is that I created a new database with the new name that replaced the old one. I guess that is how one learns the hard way ;).

Comment: Btw, I get the error saying that 'name' is not defined. Should the code be this instead?
PO2 = [act for act in bw.Database('Potato') if act['name'] == "Potato - FI - production"][0]

Comment: If you aren't sure that there is a `name`, you can use act.get('name').